# Automatic scroll to JSF validation error with p:focus and p:selectOneMenu not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a focus problem with the elem `<p :selectOneMenu>`.

I use `<p:focus>` to focus on the failed validation fields.
This is a part of my xhtml code:

```
<h:form>
    <p:focus/>

    [Some other panel and inputText]

                <p:selectOneMenu id="workCategory"
                                 value="#{personDto.category}"
                                 filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains"
                                 required="true" style="min-width: 0px !important;">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}"
                                  itemLabel="please select something"
                                  noSelectionOption="true" itemDisabled="true"/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{clientController.categoryList}"
                                   var="category" itemValue="#{category}"
                                   itemLabel="#{category.label}}"/>
                    <p:ajax event="change"
                            listener="#{clientController.doSomeJob(personDto.category)}"
                            partialSubmit="true" process="@this, @(.csrf)"
                            />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:message for="workCategory" display="text"/>

</h:form>
```

When the validation fails, the focus will be on the first element whose validation failed, which means that the page scrolls until this element. This works fine for the other elements of my page, such as inputText, switchButton … However it doesn’t seem to work for `<p:selectOneMenu>` because when it is the first element that failed validation, the page does not scroll until its position.

I checked that the `<p:selectOneMenu>` receives the class `“ui-state-focus”` when the focus event is triggered on it. Despite having `“ui-state-focus”` when the validation failed, it does not scroll as expected.
I tried to replace `<p:selectOneMenu>` with `<h:selectOneMenu>`. It works fine for `<h:selectOneMenu>` but doesn’t for `<p:selectOneMenu>`.

Why is it happening and how can I solve this issue? I need  because I cannot change so lightly to `<h:selectOneMenu>` since the whole application could be affected.

Comment: does it still fail if you remove all panels and panelGroups? Then please remove them from your example. It is one of the steps for a [mcve], please create one. Also state your PF version and test with the latest PF version?

Comment: My version of PrimeFaces is 5.3.14.

Comment: It still fails when I removed all the wrapping panels and panelGroups.

Comment: tried 6.0 or better,6.1-SNAPSHOT?

Comment: I cannot change the version because this application will soon be in production. Changing the version might affect otger components.

Comment: Like I stated so many times to others... TRY... ( I **nowhere** stated that you should use this latest version in production...) If it works in the newer version, you KNOW there has been a fix between your version and the latest and you can TRY to back-port this so you have a SOLUTION (sorry for using capitals)

Comment: Tried the new versions. Still not working.

Comment: Then please file an issue in the PF issuelist (if not already present, and it seems not when I just checked). You could debug the (javascript) source of the p:focus component to check if you find a reason it is not working